# Custom vagrant box for libvirt and ssh

Tags: kvm, qemu, vagrant, libvirt

I have followed this instruction and tried to prepare my own vagrant box:
[how to create custom vagrant box from libvirt/kvm instance?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222427/how-to-create-custom-vagrant-box-from-libvirt-kvm-instance)

Unfortunately I am facing one issue. Vagrant up hangs on:

```
==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
```

More detailed logs show me something like this:

```
D, [2018-04-04T15:51:40.628951 #6576] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.publickey[3fc61a560e58]: trying publickey (dd:3b:b8:2e:85:04:06:e9:ab:ff:a8:0a:c0:04:6e:d6)
D, [2018-04-04T15:51:40.629709 #6576] DEBUG -- socket[3fc61a8070e4]: queueing packet nr 5 type 50 len 348
D, [2018-04-04T15:51:40.629904 #6576] DEBUG -- socket[3fc61a8070e4]: sent 372 bytes
D, [2018-04-04T15:51:40.656401 #6576] DEBUG -- socket[3fc61a8070e4]: read 68 bytes
D, [2018-04-04T15:51:40.656589 #6576] DEBUG -- socket[3fc61a8070e4]: received packet nr 5 type 51 len 44
D, [2018-04-04T15:51:40.656660 #6576] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fc61a593f9c]: allowed methods: publickey,password
E, [2018-04-04T15:51:40.656709 #6576] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fc61a593f9c]: all authorization methods failed (tried none, publickey)
```

This last error doesn't appear for official boxes (like ubuntu1604).

Thing I noticed is that there is no **private_key** in following directory:

```
ls .vagrant/machines/default/libvirt/
creator_uid  id  index_uuid  vagrant_cwd
```

For example the same directory for official libvirt box (https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/ubuntu1604) looks different.

```
ls .vagrant/machines/default/libvirt/
action_provision  creator_uid  id  index_uuid  private_key  synced_folders  vagrant_cwd
```

Did I miss something during box configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been making stupid mistake. As a authorized_keys I've been using file copied from other vagrant system. So instead f using "vagrant insecure public key" I've tried to use "vagrant" pub key for that existing system.

When I used this https://raw.github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub everything started working as I expected.